# How to make a main "heading" with text and image in html?

Tags: html, css, css-position

For a study project I need to make basic website about something I love. I have been trying to create a sort of banner/heading that you see at the top of the page with a picture and a title that states what the website is for.

When I finally managed to get the text inside the image and wanted to move on to the next paragraph ( like an intro message), the text would disappear behind the banner or in front.

I tried to add a z-index and other things, but the truth is I am a supernoob with coding and I don't understand where exactly in my code it is going wrong.

I am contemplating to completely start over and try another approach regarding the`your text` banner but I am also quite curious to find out what I could do to save my code. So I can learn from it.

```css
   .banner {
        background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/shecodesio-production/uploads/files/000/055/950/original/Icelandheadingphoto.jpg?1669912436);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        background-size: cover;

    }

    .banner-text {
        color: #ffff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 140px;
        left: 120px;

    }

    .banner-text h1 {
        font-size: 100px;
        font-family: fantasy;
        margin-block-start: 0.0em;
        margin-block-end: 0.0em;

    }

    .banner-text h2 {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: fantasy;
        margin-block-end: 0em;
        margin-block-start: 0em;

    }
```

```html
<body>

<div class="banner">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/shecodesio-production/uploads/files/000/055/950/original/Icelandheadingphoto.jpg?1669912436"
        alt="iceland" style="width:100%" ; height="auto" ;>
    <div class=" banner-text">
        <h1>
            Iceland
        </h1>

        <h2>
            "The land of fire and Ice"
            <br>
            3 places you MUST visit!
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="first-place">
    <h2>Detifoss</h2>
    <p>Goðafoss is a waterfall in northern Iceland. It is located along the country's main ring road at the junction
        with the
        Sprengisandur highland road, about 45 minutes from Akureyri, Iceland's second largest city. The water of the
        river
        Skjálfandafljót falls from a height of 12 metres over a width of 30 metres.
        <br>
        It is
    </p>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you want the content of the page to flow "behind" the banner, have a look at the `fixed` (or `sticky`) position rule: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 2):

Your header was overflowing to the right side of the screen because of your

```css
top: 140px;
left: 120px;
```

If you remove it, the header won't overflow:

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/shecodesio-production/uploads/files/000/055/950/original/Icelandheadingphoto.jpg?1669912436);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner-text {
  color: #ffff;
  position: absolute;
}

.banner-text h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  margin-block-start: 0.0em;
  margin-block-end: 0.0em;
}

.banner-text h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  margin-block-end: 0em;
  margin-block-start: 0em;
}

.first-place {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="banner">

    <div class=" banner-text">
      <h1>
        Iceland
      </h1>

      <h2>
        "The land of fire and Ice"
        <br> 3 places you MUST visit!
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="first-place">
    <h2>Detifoss</h2>
    <p>Goðafoss is a waterfall in northern Iceland. It is located along the country's main ring road at the junction with the Sprengisandur highland road, about 45 minutes from Akureyri, Iceland's second largest city. The water of the river Skjálfandafljót
      falls from a height of 12 metres over a width of 30 metres.

    </p>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but..maybe I did not explain it correctly. When I do that it just moves the H1 text to the top left.   the div class first-place is still covering the rest of the image.